# Hide the Community Bulletin

Tags: script, front-page

## About

Do you ever find yourself spending too much time on Meta and not enough time answering "real" questions?

This script will hide links to per-site metas from the Community Bulletin, which is a main route to Meta.

However, featured [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com) posts, announcements, events, blog posts, and podcast links will still be shown. If none of the aforementioned special links are in the bulletin (it's only Meta links), the bulletin will be hidden entirely:

[image]

The bulletin will shrink to fit the new size if only certain links are removed:

[image: Community bulletin]

This script was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251920/provide-a-setting-to-hide-meta-posts-in-the-community-bulletin) on [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4166-hide-the-community-bulletin) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4166-hide-the-community-bulletin/code/Hide%20the%20Community%20Bulletin.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4166-hide-the-community-bulletin/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4166-hide-the-community-bulletin/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.