# Hide negatively-voted posts from the front page

Tags: script, voting, front-page

## About

The current threshold for posts on the front page is -4. Often times, that threshold is not high enough: many posts in the -3...0 range are low-quality.

This simple script hides posts with a score less than 0 from the front page.

It was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268679/hide-questions-with-negative-scores-from-front-page) on [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4216-hide-negatively-voted-posts) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4216-hide-negatively-voted-posts/code/Hide%20Negatively%20Voted%20Posts.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4216-hide-negatively-voted-posts/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4216-hide-negatively-voted-posts/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.

Comment: Ya heard of [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden)? Use it. It's *totally better*.

Comment: I'd love to, but half the time, *it doesn't work* in userscripts.

Comment: Huh? Works for me…

Comment: Maybe you're using it wrong, did you replace lines 28-29 with `questions[i].hidden = true;`?

Comment: Interesting. It refused to work before, but now, of course, it works perfectly: I'll give it a try. (I'll also have to update [this one](http://stackapps.com/questions/4844/hide-the-community-bulletin)). By the way, `questions[i].hidden = "hidden";` is what seems to work.

Comment: I'll guess the troubles were pebkac.

Comment: Who knows? Whenever I've tried to use that before, it has ended badly. Nevertheless, it's [fixed](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4216-hide-negatively-voted-posts/versions).